# How to avoid creating new folder in Azure Agent for Pipeline in Environment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have created an Azure agent environment to a virtual machine where I download builds to the folder. I have the following yaml file

```
# Python package
# Create and test a Python package on multiple Python versions. OK
# Add steps that analyze code, save the dist with the build record, publish to a PyPI-compatible index, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - Flytteordre

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  name: Azure Pipelines
variables:
  python.version: '3.6'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: build
    displayName: build
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version) copy'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    
    # We actually don't need to install these dependencies here. It needs to happen in the deploy yaml file.
    - task: CmdLine@2 
      inputs:
        script: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
          python -m pip install selenium 
          python -m pip install pdfplumber 
          python -m pip install pandas
      displayName: 'Install dependencies'
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: dist'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: Flytteordre
        ArtifactName: dist

- stage: Deployment
  displayName: Deployment stage
  jobs:
    - deployment: deploymentJob
      displayName: Deploy
      environment:
       name: Production
       resourceType: VirtualMachine
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
           steps:
           - download: none
           - downloadBuild: none
           - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
             inputs:
               buildType: 'current'
               downloadType: 'single'
               artifactName: 'dist'
               downloadPath: 'C:/azagent/A1/_work/myfolder/'
```

My problem is that each time I run the pipeline, it creates a folder inside the _work environment called 1, 2 etc.

[image]

I would like to avoid this so that I am in full control of which folders are created. As you can see I have indicated that my artifact should by downloaded to the folder path C:/azagent/A1/_work/myfolder/, however this will create two folders. One is the folder that I have indicated but the other is a folder with the title of a number. I now that this is the default but I would like to know if there is a way to turn off this default setting or at the very least to be able to change the predefined path variable PIPELINE.WORKSPACE or Agent.BuildDirectory?

Comment: *My problem is that each time I run the pipeline, it creates a folder inside the _work environment called 1, 2 etc.*. Can you please explain **why** you consider that a problem? That behavior is correct and by design. If you can explain what issue you're encountering that you're trying to solve, better guidance can be provided.

Comment: I would prefer the option of being able to name the directory myself in case I need to find a particular project and open it on the local agent. If I have 30 projects named 1,2,...30 it would take up some time for me or for another coworker to locate the exact project if we have to go in and open each folder. That is why I have the DownloadBuildArtifacts task, where I indicate the download path. This solves my problem somewhat in that I have a directory with the name of my choosing.

Comment: However with this solution I still get an unnecessary directory named "1" which I am not gong to use. If I go in and manually delete it, it will just be created in the next build. I would therefore like to know if there is a workaround to switch this deafult setting off?

Comment: I tried adding a Delete folder task at the end which deletes the newly created folder with the name "1", "2" etc. however it could not delete it as it says that there is a folder in use namely the 1/s folder, even though it is empty.

Comment: *I would prefer the option of being able to name the directory myself in case I need to find a particular project and open it on the local agent.* Why? There's no reason to go digging around in the agent's working folder. I still don't understand what problem you're trying to solve. Like I said, the behavior you're seeing is **correct** and **intentional**. Changing it is going to likely **break something**.

Comment: Yes I guess you are correct. It is best to stick with the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to avoid creating new folder in Azure Agent for Pipeline in Environment

According to the document [Agent variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services):

[image]

So, each build definition goes into its own directory within the agent's working directory.

As we know, a pipeline has input and output. Whenever we create a new pipeline, we will increment a number to name the new work folder created. The advantage of this is that multiple running builds sharing the same copy of the repository are guaranteed to step on each other sooner or later.

> I would prefer the option of being able to name the directory myself
> in case I need to find a particular project and open it on the local
> agent.

If you want open it on the local agent, you could just use the Agent variables to show the path:

```
Agent.BuildDirectory
```